# $.unique function some problems

Tags: jquery, arrays

I wanted to convert node `div` elements to `array` then if there the same arrays I wanted to get rid of them. Where is actually am I making mistake?
Thank you

**jQuery**

```
var div = $('div').get();
var arr = $.makeArray(div);
var rev = $.unique(arr);
$(rev).appendTo('body');
```

**HTML**

```
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>3</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Tuxsanov/6qe4c/)

Comment: `Sorts an array of DOM elements, in place, with the duplicates removed. Note that this only works on arrays of DOM elements, not strings or numbers.` - it checks whether 2 elements are equal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that you're assuming that `$.unique` compares the elements by their contents.

Whereas it just removes the exactly same nodes from the selection.

It could happen when you, say, use `.add()` to concatenate one selection set with another.

**UPD**: the easiest solution I could think of is http://jsfiddle.net/6qe4c/2/

```
var div = $('div');

var values = [];
div.each(function() {
    var $i = $(this),
        value = $i.text();
    if (values.indexOf(value) != -1) {
        $i.remove();
        return;
    }

    values.push(value);
});
```